# Pip installs packages in pyenv root even when virtual environment is activated

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, pyenv, virtual-environment

I try to install a package with `pip` in a virtual environement previously created with `venv`. The Python version is managed through `pyenv`. I don't want to use `pyenv` to create the virtual environment.

The project is set up this way. To the project empty directory, I added a `.python-version` containing the version `3.8.2`. Then I created my virtual environement using `python -m venv .venv`. Then I activated the environement using `source .venv/bin/activate`. Now the command line starts with a `(.env)`. However, when I try to install some package with `pip install some-package`, the package ends up in `{pyen_home}/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, instead of the virtual environment.

What's irritating is that I'm almost certain that I did manage to install package in the virtual environment that way before, but not anymore, so I don't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

Content of your `.python-version` should be `.venv`.

As far as I know you should not create this file by yourself. It generated when you run `pyenv local .venv`. And venv activates automatically.

Also proper way to create virtual environment is `pyenv virtualenv {python-version} {venv-name}`. Read the [docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) carefully.

Comment: I preferred to manage the env myself (doc says it is possible) and not use `pyenv virtualenv`, but I think I may have to resort to it in th end. Also I'm not sure about your first claim about the content of `.python-version` but thanks for pointing out `pyenv local .venv`.

Comment: What is the content of `.python-version` after you run `pyenv local .venv`? I suppose the same as in my first claim.

Comment: @runningwild, may be you accept my answer?)

Comment: If I for first create the `.venv` in the project directory with the command indicated in my question, `pyenv local .venv` returns "pyenv: version .venv not installed". This makes sense: `pyenv` looks for `.env` under the centralised `.pyenv`, like the other Python versions it manages. It doesn't look in the local directory.

Comment: I upvoted your answer as it provides useful information, however it doesn't really answer the question. I made more clear that I want to manage the virtual environement myself and not delegate it to `pyenv`. That's what I meant by "created with `venv`.